# Accidentally reused a tag in git, can I see where the tag 1.2 was used first, as it now points to a time later on than when we released the app

Tags: git, github

We released the app and tagged it as 1.2

Then shortly after we accidentally tagged 1.2 again which moved the tag forward and it now shows lots of files which aren't live, but it thinks they went out in 1.2

Can I rollback to the initial tag, or even see where it was used first?

Git tag only shows the newer tag at that point in history.

Comment: You also accidentally tagged the question as `objective-c`.

Comment: Sorry, fixed it now. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible. Your best bet might be if someone else has a clone of the repository with the old tag? Or you might be able to use a backup.

(Not sure how you could accidentally reuse a tag. It's an error to reuse an old tag and you have to use -f to force it.)

Comment: You're right, it's a long story, but the tag wasn't created. Thanks a million dude. :)